# Deform Mesh with Dynamic Paint Ridges

Tags: dynamic-paint

[image]

I’m using the Displace option in the Dynamic Paint modifier to leave an indent from one sphere on another as the first sphere orbits the second. Pretty cool, right? Wrong!

I have Subdivide Surface modifiers cranked way up on both spheres (before the Dynamic Paint). I have also added a Smooth modifier after the Dynamic Paint.

How can I smooth out the ridges you see in the trail left by the metallic sphere?

Thanks!

EDIT: Displace, not Deform

EDIT 2: Sub Steps set to 20, using Volume only on the brush

Comment: In the settings for the canvas, could you try increasing the _Sub-Steps_ value? If your brush is set to _Proximity_ or _Mesh Volume + Proximity_, you could also try adjusting its _Paint Distance_.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!

I checked the boxes for Multiply Depth and Multiply Alpha in the Brush Settings, and adjusted the Alpha Value of black in the Dynamic Paint Velocity Ramp. No more ridges!

Comment: Adjusted the alpha value to what. Could you provide a screenshot or more detailed description of your settings